# Why does `use 5.005;` have side effects?

Tags: perl

This snippet behaves differently depending on whether `use 5.005;` (or any other version) is present or not.

Why?

I didn't see anything suspicious in `perldoc -f use`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# If this is present, "Exiting\n" is printed, but the process doesn't exit.
# If commented out, exit terminates this process.
# Go figure
use 5.005;

# Open a sub-process that is "long-lived".
open FH, 'perl -e "sleep 600" |'
    or die $!;

$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    print "Exiting\n";
    exit;
};
alarm(1);

<FH>;
```

Tested on ubuntu 12.04 perl version 5.14.2 and debian squeeze perl version 5.10.1

P.S.: I'm not looking for a workaround, but an explanation.

Comment: I see the behavior you describe with Perl 5.12.4, but not with 5.18.1.  Using 5.18.1 it always acts as if the line were present.

Comment: `open` returns the pid of the child process, so you could `kill` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this behavior using Perl 5.18 on Fedora 20.  So this is something of a shot in the dark.

I believe that when you end up waiting for the child process, it's caused by Perl automatically [closing the filehandle from a piped open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) ("Closing any piped filehandle causes the parent process to wait for the child to finish, then returns the status value in `$?` and `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`).

The "shot in the dark" is that I suspect some versions of Perl didn't automatically close piped-open filehandles.  And you've managed to get that behavior, meaning that your process doesn't have to wait for the child to exit.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything official to that effect.

Comment: Interestingly `perl -MO=Concise` reveals identical optrees whether the line is there or not.